# Redirect sub.domain.com/something to www.domain.com/something

Tags: .htaccess

How I can redirect sub.domain.com/something to www.domain.com/something with .htaccess

The code that I am using is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But it only redirect the homepage.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `$1` to the end of `http://www.domain.com/` should achieve this.

You code would be something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you but it dont work. The code you give me redirect static.domain.com/something to www.domain.com but no in something page.

Comment: I have double checked it and it redirected `sub.domian.com/test/test.html` to `http://www.domian.com/test/test.html` for me, can you try it for a url you haven't tried already and/or post what is in your htaccess file?

Comment: Ok i make it work but not fit my case besause i use static.domain.com
to serve static content and this code make a lot redirection in my page i want only if user use a static link to be redirected to www page and not inside the page links